# how to extract the string from the string then convert the string to list and get only specific values from the list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

code i tried:

```
my_string = """
   interface list:
          0 - ethx
                server: 32x1-33x0  client: 33x1-34x0
                networks:
                   0 - 4cxxxx79-a4f3-4b18-b26b-377xxxx83
   cat list:
           8   0 "INTEL SSDxxxx20T8                   PHLxxP0BGN  01" - snxx, slot: 0-11
          10   0 "INTEL SSDPxxx20T8                   PHLJ9xxx0BGN  01" - snxx, slot: 0-13"""
a = my_string.split("cat list:", 1)[1]
li = a.split(" ")
mynewlist = [s for s in li if s.isdigit()]
print(mynewlist)
m = [x for x in mynewlist if not ("0" in x)]
print(m)
```

['8', '0', '10', '0']
['8']
expected:
***output get is ["8"]
expected out is ["8","10"]***

Comment: try `[x for x in mynewlist if x != '0'] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have to change the line

from

> **m = [x for x in mynewlist if not ("0" in x)]**

to

> **[x for x in mynewlist if x!='0']**

**Explanation**

```
mynewlist = ["8","0","10","0"]
```

you code **if not ("0" in x)** will execute like True , False, False , False

why third iteration also False means , "10" would also contains "0" so that it returns False , due to that "10" is not printed in your output .
Note "0" in x (your statement) will check the "0" obj present in x or not .